# How do I get a key for jsonwebtoken secret?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I am using the `jsonwebtoken` module for Node. How can I get a secret key for the `jwt.sign` function: `jwt.sign(payload, secretOrPrivateKey, [options, callback])`

According to the documentation:

> `secretOrPrivateKey` is a string, buffer, or object containing either the secret for HMAC algorithms or the PEM encoded private key for RSA and ECDSA. In case of a private key with passphrase an object { key, passphrase } can be used (based on crypto documentation), in this case be sure you pass the algorithm option.

The key used in the example was 'shhhh', but that probably isn't secure:

`var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'shhhhh');`

How can I get/generate a better secret key?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To create "secure" random passwords I like to use: `openssl rand -base64 60` on Linux.

Answer (score 5):

At first you should generate private key and public key using openssl by following two steps in command line on linux

Step1

```
openssl genrsa -out private-key.pem 1024
```

Step2.

```
openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -out public-key.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

Now you can write jwt code in this way.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const path = require('path');
const jwtPrivateKey = path.resolve('') + '/keys/private_key.pem';
const jwtPublicKey = path.resolve('') + '/keys/public_key.pem';

module.exports.generateToken = async(id, name, type) => {
  const payload = {
    id: id,
    name: name,
    type: type
  };
  const token = await  jwtSign(payload);
  return token;
};

module.exports.verifyToken = async(token) => {
  const result = await jwtVerify(token);
  return result;
};

module.exports.getPayloadFromToken = async(token) => {
  const payload = await jwtVerify(token);
  return payload;
};

const jwtSign = (payload) => {
  const options = {
    algorithm: 'RS256',
    expiresIn: '24h'
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const cert = fs.readFileSync(jwtPrivateKey);
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, cert, options);
      resolve(token);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  })
}

const jwtVerify = (token) => {
  const options = {
    algorithms: ['RS256']
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const cert = fs.readFileSync(jwtPublicKey);
      const result = jwt.verify(token, cert, options);
      resolve(result);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Generate JWT secret from terminal [image: jwt-secret-key-gen]

1. `node`
2. `require('crypto').randomBytes(64).toString('hex')`